# How to remote ls on list of files from bash shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ssh

I have a below shell script from which I am trying to copy 5 files in parallel. I am running my below shell script on `machineA` which tries to copy the  file from `machineB` and `machineC`.

If the file is not there in `machineB`, then it should be there in `machineC` for sure.

I am using GNU Parallel here to download five files in parallel. And everything works fine if all the files are there -

```
#!/bin/bash

export PRIMARY=/data01/primary
export FILERS_LOCATION_1=machineB
export FILERS_LOCATION_2=machineC
export MEMORY_MAPPED_LOCATION=/bexbat/data/be_t1_snapshot
PRIMARY_PARTITION=(550 274 2 546 278 6 558 282 10 554 286 14) # this will have more file numbers

export dir1=/bexbat/data/re_t1_snapshot/20140501

# just iterating the file and doing ls and exit if any of the file is missing
for el in "${PRIMARY_PARTITION[@]}"
do
    ssh david@$FILERS_LOCATION_1 ls $dir3/t1_weekly_1680_"$el"_200003_5.data || ssh david@$FILERS_LOCATION_2 ls $dir3/t1_weekly_1680_"$el"_200003_5.data || echo "File number $el missing on both the filers for primary partition." >&2; exit 1
done

echo "All files present. Starting to copy now."

# copy the files now
```

**Problem Statement:-**

Before copying any files, I want to see whether all the files are already present in either of the machines (machineB or machineC) or not. If any of the file is missing, then I need to print out which file is missing and exit out of the shell script with non zero status.

Above script is not working as the way I have described. If it sees any of the file is present, then it exits automatically, it's not moving in the for loop to look for other files. And I am not sure why?

Is there anything wrong I am doing?

Comment: This script is far more complex than the minimum needed to demonstrate the problem. Consider providing a SSCCE -- see http://www.sscce.org/ for details/guidance.

Comment: ...by the way, there are also a number of simpler bugs in here which http://shellcheck.net/ would ferret out for you.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Now is it better?

Comment: ...by the way, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs (the short form is that `ls` should only be used to display contents to humans, never for interpretation by scripts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ssh` doesn't preserve quoting, so you need to escape commands locally to be unescaped by the remote shell.

```
for el in "${PRIMARY_PARTITION[@]}"
do
    printf -v cmd '%q ' test -e "$dir3/t1_weekly_1680_${el}_200003_5.data"
    ssh "david@$FILERS_LOCATION_1" "$cmd" \
    || ssh "david@$FILERS_LOCATION_2" "$cmd" \
    || { echo "File number $el missing on both the filers for primary partition." >&2;
         exit 1; }
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. In your example, what is `test`?

Comment: @AKIWEB, the `test` command is the same thing as the `[` command you often see used in `if` statements and such, just with a slightly different syntax. `test -e "$file"`, like `[ -e "$file" ]` or `[[ -e $file ]]`, is the conventional way to check whether a file exists from shell.

Comment: @AKIWEB, ...the `[[ -e $file ]]` syntax is the easiest to use and most flexible, but it's not compatible with baseline POSIX sh, so `test -e "$file"` is the more widely accepted approach when you don't know what your remote system will be running.

Answer (score 1):

That `ssh` line in the loop doesn't do what you expect.  The semi-colon has a lower precedence than the other operators, so when you suffix the line with `; exit 1` that will be executed always.  You could just use an `if` statement:

```
if ! ssh david@$FILERS_LOCATION_1 ls $dir3/t1_weekly_1680_"$el"_200003_5.data && \
   ! ssh david@$FILERS_LOCATION_2 ls $dir3/t1_weekly_1680_"$el"_200003_5.data;
then
    echo "File number $el missing on both the filers for primary partition." >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought you would know `if` syntax but were just being lazy =)  I have added an example.

Comment: oops, silly me. That was simple. Need a cup of coffee. One more thing, whenever I am running your suggestion, if all the files are present, it keeps on displaying the file on the console. Is there any way to avoid seeing that message and just echo if any of the files are missing?

Comment: This is good, but it's not perfect. If the directory names don't survive double-eval, in particular, it's prone to doing interesting things. (If you had a directory with `$(rm -rf /)` in its filename, it would do not merely interesting but downright evil things).

Comment: ...also, with judicious use of the grouping operators, one can avoid needing to use `if`.